# Setting value for remote-load ComboBox

Tags: gxt

Using GXT 2.2.5 with GWT 2.3.0...

This one has stumped me. I have a RpcProxy retrieving a list of items to be displayed on a ComboBox for the user to select from. I also have a button next to the ComboBox to allow the user to create a new item. The button opens a window where the user enters the information then adds the new item to the database.

What I want to happen is that when the user closes the window at the end of the operation, the ComboBox automatically selects the new item. I identify the new item by its ID, which is passed back to the container with the ComboBox.

First I tried simply setting the ComboBox value:

```
Item item = comboBox.getStore().findModel("id", id);
if (item != null)
{
  comboBox.setValue(item);
}
```

That didn't work; as far as I could tell, the ComboBox was not reloading the data, so the new item didn't exist to be selected.

So, next I tried reloading the store before selecting:

```
comboBox.getStore().getLoader().load();
Item item = comboBox.getStore().findModel("id", id);
if (item != null)
{
  comboBox.setValue(item);
}
```

That didn't work either; the value still didn't get selected.

Finally, I tried creating a temporary LoadListener to make sure the store was reloaded before making the selection:

```
LoadListener listener = new LoadListener()
{
  @Override
  public void loaderLoad(LoadEvent le)
  {
    super.loaderLoad(le);
    Item item = comboBox.getStore().findModel("id", id);
    if (item != null)
    {
      comboBox.setValue(item);
    }
  }
};
comboBox.getStore().getLoader().addLoadListener(listener);
comboBox.getStore().getLoader().load();
comboBox.getStore().getLoader().removeLoadListener(listener);
```

Still no joy. Some checking revealed that the listener wasn't even being invoked.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the `combobox.setUseQueryCache(false);` to reload the combobox every time ?

Comment: I did, and it didn't help. For some reason, the findModel() method is not finding the new item (i.e., it returns null), even though expanding the comboBox shows it to be in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the store listener in storeDataChanged method
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?73979-How-to-manually-select-an-item-(combobox)

```
store.addStoreListener(new StoreListener<BeanModel>(){
        @Override
        public void storeDataChanged(StoreEvent<BeanModel> se) {                
            super.storeDataChanged(se);         

            BeanModel item = se.getStore().findModel("id", id);
            if(item != null){
                //grid.getSelectionModel().select(item, false);
                comboBox.setValue(item);
            }

        }
    });
```